# undefined returned in alertbox jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The following code resides in my php file (cl.php):

```
<?php for( $i = 0; $i < count( $getClFormData->data ); $i++ ) :?>
<tr>
    <input type='hidden' name='itemid[]' value='<?php echo $getClFormData->data[$i]['c_item_id'] ?>'>
    <td><?php echo $getClFormData->data[$i]['item'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $getClFormData->data[$i]['description'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $getClFormData->data[$i]['norm'] ?></td>
    <td>
        <input type='radio' name='kforce_mont1_<?php echo $i ?>' value='1' class='bobtailradiook'>OK<br/>
        <input type='radio' name='kforce_mont1_<?php echo $i ?>' value='0' class='bobtailradionok' alt='<?php echo $getClFormData->data[$i]['c_item_id'] ?>'>NOK
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endfor;
```

where `<input type='radio' name='kforce_mont1_<?php echo $i ?>' value='0' class='bobtailradionok' alt='<?php echo $getClFormData->data[$i]['c_item_id'] ?>'>NOK` is relevant to my question.

Further down cl.php, the following code:

```
if(isset($_POST['itemid'])){
    <input type='hidden' class='test' value='<?php echo $_POST['itemid']; ?>'>
}
```

**JS Code**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.bobtailradionok').each(function() {
        $( this ).click(function() {
            //$("#errortable").show();
            //alert($(this).attr('alt'));
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: {itemid: $(this).attr('alt')},
                url: "cl.php",
                success:function(data){
                    alert($('.test').val());
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The jquery above returns 'undefined' in the alertbox, while I want it to return the itemid. Why is 'undefined' returned? Since, `<input type='hidden' class='test' value='<?php echo $_POST['itemid']; ?>'>` is correctly returned as `<input type='hidden' class='test' value='1'>` or `<input type='hidden' class='test' value='2'>` depending on the box clicked, when I look in the console.log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you ever add the AJAX response to the page?

This is showing you what's in the response:

```
console.log(data)
```

But *this* is looking for a `class="test"` element *on the page*:

```
$('.test').val()
```

Did you mean to add the response to the page somewhere first?  For example:

```
$('#someElement').append(data);
alert($('.test').val());
```

Or perhaps specifically look in the response for the value?:

```
$('.test', data).val()
```

or:

```
$(data).find('.test').val()
```

Basically you're just looking for your `class="test"` element in the wrong place.